# Object of main activity in result activity not properly accessing boolean variable?

Tags: java, android

I have a main class that holds two array lists of class objects.  Long story short, I'm calling an activity via startActivityForResult to get a return of the position of a spinner item selection.  I have two boolean variables in the main activity that basically tell the application which list is being worked with: booleans listASelected and listBSelected.  If listASelected = true, then listBSelected  = false and visa-versa.  In the result activity I basically generate the spinner this way:

```
MainActivity mainAct = new MainAtivity();
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    for(int i = 0;i<mainAct.pickThreeNumbers.size(); i++){
        optionsPickThree.add(mainAct.pickThreeNumbers.get(i).getNumbers(1)+mainAct.pickThreeNumbers.get(i).getNumbers(2)+mainAct.pickThreeNumbers.get(i).getNumbers(3));
    }
    for(int r = 0; r<mainAct.pickFourNumbers.size();r++){
        optionsPickFour.add(mainAct.pickFourNumbers.get(r).getNumbers(1)+mainAct.pickFourNumbers.get(r).getNumbers(2)+mainAct.pickFourNumbers.get(r).getNumbers(3)+mainAct.pickFourNumbers.get(r).getNumbers(4));
    }

    if(mainAct.pickThreeSelected){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, optionsPickThree);
    }else{
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, optionsPickFour);
    }
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, I use this to do my setResult.

```
Intent output = new Intent();
        if(mainAct.pickThreeSelected){
            output.putExtra("slot", position);
            output.putExtra("list", "PickThree");
        }else{
            output.putExtra("slot", position);
            output.putExtra("list", "PickFour");
    } 
        setResult(1,output);
        finish();
    }
```

The issue is that nomatter what it always works as if mainAct.pickThreeSelected = true, even if I know it is false because other sections of the app are functioning properly.  What I assume is happening is that the class object is accessing the variable's initialized values instead of their current values at the time of execution.  That, or I'm an idiot and there's a different way to accomplish this.

Any help, fellas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make pickThreeSelected as static. That way you will update the same instance everytime.

Comment: That did it.  I wish I could figure out exactly what "static" means and what the difference is between a static variable and a non-static variable... I must be illiterate because I've read the documentation a hundred times and the concept still eludes me.  Thanks, bruddah!

Answer (score 0):

What is the default value that you have set to the mainAct.pickThreeSelected??If its true,make it as false.Then if user selects the listA change the value to true.

Comment: Initially pickThreeSelected is true,and pickFourSelected is false, because the application starts with pickThreeSelected as default.  If the user selects the Pick Four button, it changes the value of PickThreeSelected to false and PickFourSelected to true and changes the UI to the PickFour UI.  Even if I select the "Remove" button in the Pick Four UI, with PickFourSelected currently set to true and pickThreeSelected set to false, it still operates as if pickThreeSelected is true.

Comment: Are you sure that the pickThreeSelected value is set to false when the user selects the Pick Four button??

Comment: Absolutely sure.  Other aspects of the application rely on these two values being accurate for certain things to happen, and everything else is and has been functioning properly.